# Hibernate @AttributeOverrides on multiple attributes without explicitly naming each one

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, seam, java-ee-6

Setup: Hibernate 4.0 (JPA 2.0), Java EE 6

I have the following problem: I have a class "HandAttributes" annotated with @Embeddable which holds a lot of boolean attributes. In another class "Person" I want to embed this class **twice**. The idea is, that the values in the class "Attributes" represent attributes the "Person" can have on its left and right hand.

As far as I understand the possibilites with @AttributeOverride, I could override each attribute in the HandAttributes class and give them a new Column name i.e. "BrokenNailRight" and "BrokenNailLeft". But as I mentioned, there are many of those Attributes, so I would like to rather not override them all explicitly.

Is there a possibility to Override **all** attributes in the Embeddable class by giving some kind of naming pattern? Like *add the String "left" to all columns* or anything similar.

I hope the question is understandable and I'm looking forward any ideas you might have!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a possibility to Override all attributes in the Embeddable
>   class?

I've never heard of something like this and am pretty sure that this is not possible.

Are you sure that you want to *embed* these objects? This results in a lot of really static code, that might better be written like this:

```
public class Human {
Hand leftHand;
Hand rightHand;
...
}
```

or even

```
public class Alien {
Map<ConnectedBodyPart, Hand> hands
...
}
```

This should also enable generic versions of `getBrokenNails()`...